# Automated REST testing tool for MAC

Tags: rest, automated-tests

I'm currently using POSTMAN and Advanced Rest Client application to test my REST endpoints. These tool are great and make it very nice for testing. I am currently entering these calls manually and testing. However, I have a number of endpoints which have prerequisite calls that need to be made to handle their dependencies.

This is not a big deal, however if there is a way I can chain these calls to run in a certain flow waiting for the prerequisite to be completed before running the next I could harshness this to craft a fully automated API testing suite. Which, would give more flexibility rather than manually entering them.

Comment: Did you try Selenium?

Comment: What did you mean by MAC?

Answer (score 1):

Postman let's you do this using the [Jetpacks upgrade](http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/). You can then use the recently released [Newman](http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/05/12/meet-newman-a-command-line-companion-for-postman/) tool to run them through the command line.